# How does one code a number x into a quantum state?

Tags: quantum-computing

We have 4 numbers x = [x1, x2, x3, x4]

We want to prepare quantum state Psi somehow to encode x

We want to make QFT on Psi to get Phi = QFT (Psi)

Answer (score 1):

For QFT, the numbers on which the transform is applied are encoded as amplitudes of the basis states: |x⟩ = ∑ xₖ |k⟩.

In your case you'd use a 2-qubit state and use amplitudes x₀ ... x₃, normalized. Then you'd prepare a state x₀ |00⟩ + x₁ |10⟩ + x₂ |01⟩ + x₃ |10⟩ (assuming little-endian encoding of the basis states). If you're implementing this using some quantum programming language, there's likely to be a library to do that for you - for example, in Q# it's [PrepareArbitraryState](https://learn.microsoft.com/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.preparation.preparearbitrarystate).

Comment: This is part of a set up, so that I can then apply the Quantum Fourier Transform. I have to figure it out  via pen and paper before I code it. Thanks for the answer, it's steering me in the right direction